# How to chose value of Block and thread in Cuda?

Tags: cuda

I m new with cuda. I m writing code for image processing in cuda.
My c and cuda code is below and i tried to convert into cuda, but it not works well.

My C code :

```
void imageProcess_usingPoints(int point, unsigned short *img)
{
    // doing image process here using point variable value.
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 /* here i define and initialize some variable */

    int point=0;
    unsigned short *image_data;
     // consider that here i read image and store all pixels value in *image_data.

 for(int i=0;i<1050;i++,point+=1580)
 {


    // calling image process function like bluring image.
    imageProcess_usingPoints(point,image_data);
    /* doing some image process  using that point value on 16 bit grayscale image.*/
 } 


 return 0;
}
```

i tried to convert my c code into cuda, but its wrong.
 So, my cuda code that what ever i tried is below.

```
__global__ void processOnImage(int pointInc)
{
     int line = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
     int point=((line)*pointInc));
      /* here i m not getting exact vaue of point variable as same like in c code */
    /* doing image processing here using point value */

}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 /* here i define and initialize some variable */

    int pointInc=1580;
    static const int BLOCK_WIDTH = 25;
    int x = static_cast<int>(ceilf(static_cast<float>(1050) / BLOCK_WIDTH));
    const dim3 grid (x,1);
    const dim3 block(BLOCK_WIDTH,1);
    processOnImage<<<grid,block>>>(pointInc);

 return 0;
}
```

In processOnImage function of cuda code i m not getting exact value of point(int point) variable  as in above c code. so what i m doing wrong in cuda code. Or how to use that block and thread for my code in c.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you could set threads per block to a multiple of `warpSize` (or just a multiple of 32)

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#warpsize

Usually 256 is a good one for most simple kernels. The exact number has to be tuned. This tool in the CUDA installation dir can also help you choose the number.

```
$CUDA_HOME/tools/CUDA_Occupancy_Calculator.xls
```

After determining the thread number per block, you could then calculated the block number required by your data size. The following example shows how to do that.

https://developer.nvidia.com/content/easy-introduction-cuda-c-and-c

On the other hand, you could also use a fixed number of blocks for arbitrary data size. Sometimes you could get higher performance by this way. See this for more details.

https://developer.nvidia.com/content/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops

Comment: but how do i increase point variable by multiple of 1580 in every thread of block in cuda as like in my code C. Means in my kernel how to use or access point varible as in my c code?

Comment: @Jay not quite understand your code. could you give a meaningful one, at least including the image data.

Comment: Now i had edit in my c code. Please see only C Code, and can you suggest to me how to convert that C code into CUDA ? In my C code, suppose there is not using int Point variable in for loop. then i had done convert that C code into CUDA. But when i add int point variable in for loop, and then i can't understand that how to increase int point variable value in CUDA ?