# cuda big-matrix and blocks/threads

Tags: matrix, cuda

I'm having some issues regarding how to handle big matrices. Like explained [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586434/cuda-matrix-problems) I've a program which does work on big square matrices (like 5k-10k). The computational part is correct (still not 100% optimized) and I've tested it with smaller square matrices (like 256-512). Here is my code:

```
#define N 10000
#define RADIUS 100
#define SQRADIUS RADIUS*RADIUS
#define THREADS 512

//many of these device functions are declared
__device__ unsigned char avg(const unsigned char *src, const unsigned int row, const unsigned int col) {
    unsigned int sum = 0, c = 0;

    //some work with radius and stuff

    return sum;
}

__global__ void applyAvg(const unsigned char *src, unsigned char *dest) {
    unsigned int tid = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x, tmp = 0;
    unsigned int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    int col = tid%N, row = (int)tid/N;

    while(tid < N*N) {
        if(row * col < N * N) {
            //choose which of the __device__ functions needs to be launched
        }

        tid += stride;
        col = tid%N, row = (int)tid/N;
    }
    __syncthreads();
}

int main( void ) {
    cudaError_t err;
    unsigned char *base, *thresh, *d_base, *d_thresh, *avg, *d_avg;
    int i, j;

    base = (unsigned char*)malloc((N * N) * sizeof(unsigned char));
    thresh = (unsigned char*)malloc((N * N) * sizeof(unsigned char));
    avg = (unsigned char*)malloc((N * N) * sizeof(unsigned char));

    err = cudaMalloc((void**)&d_base, (N * N) * sizeof(unsigned char));
    if(err != cudaSuccess) {printf("ERROR 1"); exit(-1);}
    err = cudaMalloc((void**)&d_thresh, (N * N) * sizeof(unsigned char));
    if(err != cudaSuccess) {printf("ERROR 2"); exit(-1);}
    err = cudaMalloc((void**)&d_avg, (N * N) * sizeof(unsigned char));
    if(err != cudaSuccess) {printf("ERROR 3"); exit(-1);}

    for(i = 0; i < N * N; i++) {
        base[i] = (unsigned char)(rand() % 256);
    }

    err = cudaMemcpy(d_base, base, (N * N) * sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if(err != cudaSuccess){printf("ERROR 4"); exit(-1);}

    //more 'light' stuff to do before the 'heavy computation'

    applyAvg<<<(N + THREADS - 1) / THREADS, THREADS>>>(d_thresh, d_avg);

    err = cudaMemcpy(thresh, d_thresh, (N * N) * sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if(err != cudaSuccess) {printf("ERROR 5"); exit(-1);}
    err = cudaMemcpy(avg, d_avg, (N * N) * sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if(err != cudaSuccess) {printf("ERROR 6"); exit(-1);}

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

When launching the problem with a big matrix (like 10000 x 10000) and a radius of 100 (which is how 'far' from every point in the matrix i look ahead) it takes so much time.

I believe that the problem resides both in the `applyAvg<<<(N + THREADS - 1) / THREADS, THREADS>>>` (how many blocks and threads I decide to run) and in the `applyAvg(...)` method (the stride and the tid).
Can someone clarify me which is the best way to decide how many blocks/threads to launch given that the matrix can vary from 5k to 10k size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose what you want to do is image filtering/convolution. based on your current cuda kernel, two thing you could do to improve the performance.

1. Use 2-D threads/blocks to avoid `/` and `%` operators. They are very slow.
2. Use shared memory to reduce global memory bandwidth.

Here's a white paper about image convolution. It shows how to implement a high performance box filer with CUDA.

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/3_Imaging/convolutionSeparable/doc/convolutionSeparable.pdf

Nvidia cuNPP library also provides functions nppiFilterBox() and nppiFilterBox(), so you don't need write your own kernel. Here's the document and example.

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#box-filter-with-npp

NPP doc pp.1009 http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pdf/NPP_Library.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Yes it's a sort of filtering. I really messed up how blocks/threads work...lets say I have a 10000 x 10000 matrix where every pixel needs to be filtered, which is the best way to launch my kernels? At the moment I'm launching about 20 blocks each with 512 threads, right? Is there another way to better use the 65k blocks? Or it is more performant to use threads? I'm kinda new to CUDA and everything seems so messy with all these blocks/threads per blocks xD

Comment: For 2D task I suggest you use 16x16 threads/block and 625x625 block/grid. There's no need to maximize the number of blocks. See here for 1D task. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422993/how-to-chose-value-of-block-and-thread-in-cuda/19423751#19423751

Comment: Thank you again, you were really helpful. I'm going to read the paper you linked me...you deserve the green tick ;)